# Iteratively adding a row containing characters and numbers to a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, append

I have a `list` containing named elements. I am iterating over the list names, performing the computation for each corresponding element, "encapsulating" the results and the name in a vector and finally adding the vector to a table. The row or vector after each iteration contains a mix of characters and numbers.
The first row is getting added but from the second row onwards there is a problem.
In this example, there is supposed to be one column (first) containing alphanumeric names. All rows after the first one contain NAs.

```
x <- list(a_1=c(1,2,3), b_2=c(3,4,5), c_3=c(5,1,9))

df <- data.frame()
for(name in names(x))
{
  tmp <- x[[name]]
  m <- mean(tmp)
  s <- sum(tmp)
  df <- rbind(df, c(name,m,s))
}

df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

I know there are possibly more efficient ways but for the moment this is more intuitive for me as it is assuring that each computation is associated with a particular name. There can be several columns and rows and the names are extremely helpful to join tables, query, compare etc. They make it easier to trace back results to a particular element in my original list.

Additionally, I would be glad to know other ways in which the element names are always retained while transforming.

Thankyou!

Comment: I execute your code and get the expected dataframe, without any problem nor NAs...

Comment: Thats bizzare! I just tried it again. Only the first row is populated

Comment: you may try cleaning your data...

Comment: It is still strange because I am getting the same problem in a new RStudio session. But it is working fine on a different computer

Comment: IIRC the default for stringsAsFactors was changed to FALSE in R 4.0.0. If the default is set to FALSE there is no need to set it within rbind. The default can also be changed in R versions before 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set stringsAsFactors = FALSE in rbind. With stringsAsFactors = TRUE the first iteration in the loop converts the string variables into factors (with the factor levels being the values).

```
x <- list(a_1=c(1,2,3), b_2=c(3,4,5), c_3=c(5,1,9))

df <- data.frame()
for(name in names(x))
{
  tmp <- x[[name]]
  m <- mean(tmp)
  s <- sum(tmp)
  df <- rbind(df, c(name,m,s), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

An easier solution would be to utilize sapply().

```
x <- list(a_1=c(1,2,3), b_2=c(3,4,5), c_3=c(5,1,9))
df <- data.frame(name = names(x), m = sapply(x, mean), s = sapply(x, sum))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works on the computer that was giving me trouble. Yes, the versions are different.